# Unable to use pywinauto to connect to "Open" dialog window in Google Chrome when selenium to upload image in Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, pywinauto

Using Seleniumwebdriver, I was able to automate the login and navigate to profile and change the view to Mobile view. Then used the code below to click on the "+" icon.
The Open Dialog window opens but pywinauto was not able to connect it. There was No error message also, once i close the browser, then i get the error message saying unable to find the Mentioned window

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]""").click()

app=Application().connect(title=u'Open',class_name='#32770')

app.Open.print_control_identifiers()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am working with pywinauto these days.

My code looks like this:

```py
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application()
upload_files_window = app.connect(title=u'Open', found_index=0)
```

and works well.

So would you like to try:

```py
app = pywinauto.Application()
chose_a_name = app.connect(title=u'Open',class_name='#32770')
chose_a_name.Open.print_control_identifiers()
```